# Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 3499 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true." FLUTTER

Tags: flutter

I work in flutter project, and i have a problem that :
the project composed from three Pages (splash.dart, login.dart, dashboard.dart), when the app launch the splash.dart page opened, and i passe the new user to login.dart page, and when he put a valid credentials i passe he to dashboard.dart page but in this second passage i got the error below "[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 3499 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true."
Also when i want to display an alert to inform the user to put a valid credentials when he put invalid credentials a got the same problem
thanks in advance,

Comment: No, It is not the same problem, also it doesn't have a correct answer

Comment: how about this? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36177#issuecomment-650713430

Comment: @alecsam thanks its a correct response

Comment: hey @WaelMessaadi your problem is solved?

Comment: @AbhishekGhaskata, yes it solved

Answer (score 0):

The method you use for page redirection should look like this:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: RouteSettings(name: OtherPage.routeName),
          builder: (context) => OtherPage(),
        ),
      );
```

If this method doesn't fix your problem, be careful where you define it in the builder widget and make sure you don't use *BuildContext* in unnecessary places

Answer (score 0):

Utils.flushBarSuccessMessage ("Data Received Successfully", context);

Navigator.pop(context);

Make sure do not use like this flush bar or snackbar or other services are running who takes context and navigate

Sure to avoid run navigation code during flush bar or snackbar building

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).